# iferror error when translate it to vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to mimic iferror formula using vba

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C4,E:E,1,FALSE),"Test")
```

When I tried to code the exact same thing, the error is pointing to ""Test""
Is there a way not to use ""?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[-1]C[-4],C[-2],1,FALSE)," & ""Test"" & ")"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change it to `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[-1]C[-4],C[-2],1,FALSE)," & """Test""" & ")"`

Comment: No real need for & there: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[-1]C[-4],C[-2],1,FALSE),""Test"")"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i never know how many `"` to put in those cases, I prefer to use `ChrW(34)`

This should work easily :

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[-1]C[-4],C[-2],1,FALSE)," & _
        ChrW(34) & "Test" & ChrW(34) & ")"
```

If you have a doubt on ChrW or AsciiW :

```
MsgBox AscW("""")
MsgBox ChrW(34)
```

Comment: Accept answer to close subject! ;)